# (C++) A simpler way to compare a value to every element of an array with the OR operator?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, compare, operators

I'm trying to build a calculator in c++ using classes, and i came accross this issue. here's the code:
(it's not really an issue right now, but i can see it becoming one in the future)

```
char opcheck;
char opDisp[6] = { '+', '-', '*', '/', 'p', 'r' };

while (opcheck==opDisp[0] || opcheck==opDisp[1] || opcheck==opDisp[2] || opcheck==opDisp[2] || opcheck==opDisp[4] || opcheck==opDisp[5]);
```

So, my issue is with that while statement; how can i compare the variable opcheck with every element of the opDisp array WITHOUT typing out "opcheck==opDisp[n]" for every element?

Does C++ even have any built-in array function thing like **"if(opcheck==opDisp[from 1 to 5 with the OR operator each time])"**?

Comment: Make it a struct and define the `operator=` member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)

```
while (std::find(std::begin(opDisp), std::end(opDisp), opcheck) != std::end(opDisp))
```

Comment: But why is it checking if whatever value i found with std::find is not equal to the end of the array? I'm not quite familiar with this...

Comment: `std::find` returns iterator of first found element, or end if not found.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`any_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) from the standard algorithms from C++11 onwards:

```
if (std::any_of(std::cbegin(opDisp), std::cend(opDisp), [=](char x) { return x == opcheck; })) {
    ...
}
```

Or in C++20 with `std::ranges`:

```
if (std::ranges::any_of(opDisp, [=](auto x) { return x == opcheck; })) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't ask (about efficiency), but do you HAVE to use an array? Any search in array will have linear complexity. If you keep your operators in an `unordered_set` (hash table), the search will have constant complexity, and the same `std::find` will work, just faster.

Comment: So, is it recommended to always use an unordered set when you don't need to have the values inside of a container to be in a specific order?

Comment: @SorenTheOutcast You use ordered collections if you care about the order of their elements, and unordered - if you don't. This applies to `map` and `unordered_map`, too.